# Sketching the wavefunction of an electron in a cosine potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

Let an electron is moving in 1D in a periodic cosine potential $V(x)=V_0\cos\alpha x$ where $\alpha$ is a constant of dimension $[L]^{-1}$ and $V_0$ has dimension of energy. The Schrodinger equation for an energy eigenstate with energy $E$ takes the form $$-\frac{\hslash^2}{2m}\psi^{\prime\prime}+(V_0\cos\alpha x-E)\psi=0.$$ Since the potential is periodic, by Bloch's theorem the wavefunctions $\psi$ must be of the form $\psi(x)=e^{ikx}u(x)$ where $k$ is an some unknown continuous parameter of dimension $[L]^{-1}$ and $u(x)$ is a periodic function with period $2\pi\alpha^{-1}$. This equation cannot be solved exactly to find $u(x)$. Does anyone have any idea how to sketch the wavefunction $\psi(x)$  or the profile of position probability density $p(x)=\psi^*\psi$? I would expect that $p(x)$ is maximized at the minima and minimized at the maxima of the potential.

**Note** As of now, this question has a few close votes. Please let me know if this is more suitable for Mathematics or Mathematica stackexchange or if I need to explain something in more detail.

Comment: It's solvable exactly in terms of Mathieu functions.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest sketch is when the wave vector matches the periodicity of the potential. There are then two standing-wave solutions: one with maximum electron density at the minima of the potential, one with maximum density at the maxima of the potential. The difference in energy is the gap between two branches of the dispersion curve for other k-values.